# Why was this tag deleted and added in the same revision?

Tags: support, tags, editing

After editing a question's tags, its [revisions page](https://askubuntu.com/posts/44726/revisions) indicates that the *r* tag was both removed and added by me. Why wasn't it just left untouched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a side-effect of how the revision list calculates changes to tags, combined with how tags are sorted...

First the easy one: the tag list is compared *in-place* - so if a tag is moved from position #1 to position #4, it'll show up in the diff as being removed and then added.

Now comes the twist: tags are automatically ordered by frequency of use, but this is done only when a new revision is saved. So when your first revision was created on Stack Overflow, where [r](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/r) outranks [latex](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/latex), `r` came first. When the tags were edited again after the migration, they were re-ordered to reflect their frequency here on AskUbuntu - where [r](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/r) is much, *much* less common. So it "moved".